# Auto-Scroll PDF's every minute

Tags: pdf, scrolling, adobe-reader

Is there a way to automatically scroll PDF files one page every few minutes.

I see [this feature advertised](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/new.html) in Foxit's reader for Linux, where it is called Time-Lapse Scroll.
However, this option is absent from their Windows Reader, as well as Adobe's reader.

I am happy to use any other reader (VIM?), or to run a powershell or equiv. script if I only knew what to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Copy and paste the following in to a new file and save as `autoscroll.ahk`:

```
IfWinActive ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow
{
    Loop
    {
    Sleep 60000
    send  {PgDn}
    }
}
```

Sleep is in milliseconds, so `60000` is one minute. You can change this to whatever you want.

Simply run this file, and it should automatically press Page Down automatically. To exit, right click on the icon in the taskbar and choose exit.

You will have to set the zoom level correctly in your reader application to make sure that page down will go to the next page - If not, this script can be modified to the shortcut that does that.

Replace AcrobatSDIWindow with the ahk_class listed for your PDF reader by running AU3_Spy.exe (included with AHK) and focusing on your target application.

Comment: This sounds great, will try. One Q though - will it not scroll any program that is open?  If so, is there a way I can tell it only to scroll the PDF reader?

Comment: @SamGoody There is... but, I am not an AutoHotKey Expert... Give me a few minutes, and I will try to find the command.

Comment: @SamGoody - Ok Done.

Answer (score 1):

[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) now has the AutoScroll ability build in for Windows

[image]